# SMS conversation with MobileConnect

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

Does anyone have experience handling MO (inbound) SMS messages in MobileConnect? Our use case is sending an outbound message to a contact from within Salesforce. If the contact replies how can we see/capture the response? Are we limited to the Text Response template with a Keyword? Does this work differently with a private short code instead of a shared short code? Any help/advice is appreciated.

Comment: Is "from within Salesforce" referring to Marketing Cloud or CRM/Force.com? What is the perceived limitation of Text Response?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your use case and what you want to have happen, is important to note the following regarding your solution.

**To send an SMS from Salesforce, you need to initiate the SMS using:**

- APEX Call to create the SMS sende via the MC API
- Salesforce Entry Event in Journey Builder, and send the SMS via Journey Builder (note: The contact needs to exists in MobileConnect and opt'ed in to a keyword on the BU here)

When receiving a text-response or whatever flow you have, again, you have a couple of options - but the main thing to consider comes down to your contact model (does the same mobile number exist more than once?).

**Overall what you need to ensure is that:**

- The subscriber within mobile connect has an attribute with the SFID stored
- And, depending on use case, that your SubscriberKey is equal to the SFID

**What this enables is that:**

- When you receive a text, you could use AMPscript to pull the the SFID variable, and the use that variable to create whatever you want to inside Salesforce Core (using CreateSalesforceObject)
- If you use the SFID as SubscriberKey, you could also just add a row to a data extension which would allow you to inject people into a journey, which, would allow for the journey to control bevahior and record creation inside Salesforce Core.

Comment: I received a requeriment to send a SMS to a customer to confirm a visit on store. If he/she reply the SMS with "1" I can confirm the visit and change the Status of Event in SalesCloud. I understood your propose but where can I use AMPscript do use CreateSalesforceObject? Is there any kind of trigger on "Received text message response"?